# Index Sort: serialization of data stream based on index

Tags: sorting, c++11, serialization, indexing, data-stream

I have two streams from where I am getting the data. I would like to output a stream sorted by indexes of two current stream. 
for simplicity here is sample code:

```
While (1)
{
read.stream1(buffer1,size);
read.stream2(buffer2,size);


int index1 = (int) buffer1[20];
int index2 = (int) buffer2[20];


///// This is the part which I have to do:
sort based on the index, which ever index is small 
send that.
outputbuffer = Sort(index1,buffer1,index2,buffer2);
/////

outputstream.send(outputbuffer);

}
```

we have no information about the incomings of indexes, its like continuous sorting of data stream i.e serialization.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the indexes contain. The example code reads data into buffers, then sets index1 to the content of buffer1[20], and index2 to the content of buffer2[20]. Perhaps the idea was to declare index1 as a pointer to int, and then allocate (new) 20 integers for it?